# Magento coupon getDiscountAmount() ?

Tags: magento, discount, coupon

```
$coupon = Mage::getModel('salesrule/coupon');
$couponCollection = $coupon->getCollection();
foreach($couponCollection as $c){
echo 'Code:'.$c->getCode().'--->Discount Amount:'.$c->getDiscountAmount().'<br />';
}
```

Found this piece somewhere here on stackoverflow. The discount amount is not showing.. Can somebody help me get this value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
$coupon = Mage::getModel('salesrule/coupon');
```

to:

```
$coupon = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule');
```

`getDiscountAmount` doesn't exist in `/app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Coupon.php` but does show up in `/app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Rule.php`